# HostBuilderExtensions for custom Serilog logging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serilog

How do I test if the extension below is working as intended? It should first be loading configuration from appsettings.json and then the user should be able to override some of the configuration using the `Action<T>` parameter.

```cs
public static class HostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddSerilogCustomLogging(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<LoggerConfiguration>? configure = null)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);

        return builder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);

            configure?.Invoke(loggerConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it should be like above or the other way around (below).

```cs
public static class HostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddSerilogCustomLogging(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<LoggerConfiguration>? configure = null)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);

        return builder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            var config = loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);

            configure?.Invoke(config);
        });
    }
}
```

How do I validate to myself that it works as intended?